# Xml Serialization and Deserialization problem of DatabindingList of Objects

Tags: c#, xml, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I try to serialize and deserialize an xml file. The code in C# works perfectly well on Widows. But when I try to do it on ubuntu with mono, It fails for DataBindingList of Objects. The process was working 6 mouths ago. It doesn't seem like it is a ubuntu or a mono version problem since I used both the most recent versions of them and 3 years ago versions. I use the "Oracle WM VirtualBox 6.0" on Windows 10.

During the serialization items of the BindingList are not regonized (and not writen on the xml file). And the deserialization crash at the line where is the first item of the BindingDataList with the error: "System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

It could be a binding problem or a problem of high level xml mark. Maybe the xml is too nested.

Here What I want to serialize/deserialize:

```
    [Serializable, XmlInclude(typeof(WeatherFileFormat)), Bindable(true)]
    public class WeatherFile : Child<string>, IWithPath
    {
        private string relativeFileName;

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "file")]
        [Editor(typeof(FileNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string File
        {
            get {

                 return "../MyFile.txt"; 
            }
            set
            {
               relativeFileName=newRelativeFileName="../MyFile.txt"

            }
        }
     }


    [Serializable, XmlInclude(typeof(WeatherFile)),XmlInclude(typeof(WeatherFileFormat)),   XmlInclude(typeof(BaseBindingList<WeatherFile>))]
    public class SiteItem : ProjectDataFileItem1Child<WeatherFile, string, WeatherFileGenerator>, IWithPath
    {
    


       [XmlElement("WeatherFiles",typeof(BaseBindingList<WeatherFile>))]
        public BaseBindingList<WeatherFile> WeatherFiles { get { return BindingItems1; }}

}
```

This is what I obtain during serialization:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
  <SiteItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-instance" name="" format="YearJdayMinMaxRainRad">
   <WeatherFiles />
  </SiteItem>
```

For the sake of simplycity I sum up the code and the xml. For example "name" and "format" are attribute of "SiteItem" which are not represented in this post but which are well taken into account.

Here is what I try to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
  <SiteItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-instance" name="MyName" format="YearJdayMinMaxRainRad">
<ItemArray>
   <WeatherFiles>
     <WeatherFile file=""../MyFile.txt"" />
   </WeatherFiles>
</ItemArray>
  </SiteItem>
```

It crashes at the line were appears the mark *WeatherFile*

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Looks like you have stray quotation marks in the `WeatherFile` node for your file attribute.

Comment: Thanks Mattew, for your answer. The problem is not the quotation mark, here it is a problem of copy and paste in this post. I spent a lot of time on this bug and I am pretty sure it is not a easy problem to solve.